# Why isn't the parent method being called?

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance

I have class B that inherits class A, both are in in C#. They both have a Value property, class A is defined as such:

```
public object Value
{
     get 
     { [...] }
     set 
     { [...] }
}
```

Class B's property goes like this :

```
public new decimal Value
{
    get
    { [...] }
    set
    { [...] }
}
```

The code below is in VB, we use it like this :

```
Dim var1 As new B
var1.Value = "abc"
```

The problem is that instead of calling the class A property because the class B doesn't have a definition for Value as a string, it tries to convert the string in decimal before sending it to class B's Value property. "abc" not being a valid number it throws an exception, but I have treatment for such value in class A's Value property.

Anyway for it not to convert the string to decimal and call class A's property instead of class B's?

Comment: You should enable `Option Strict`.

Comment: it is because the `new ` keyword in B's Value is **hiding** the base Value. If you want to target base property you must use an explicit cast to the base type

Comment: The question would be more clear for the Value properties to be wrapped in a class definition block so it can be determined at a glance which class the Value properties belong to

Comment: @taquion  An explicit cast is cumbersome and potentially bad style.  Also the cast may break if the Value property is moved to a different class in the hierarchy.  This created tightly bound code which will make the code more difficult to maintain in the future

Comment: @Steve I totally agree with you. My comment was a direct response to the "second" OP's question: _Anyway for it not to convert the string to decimal and call class A's property instead of class B's?_ I generally try to avoid going further the questions as to recommend not to do that or to do something else, as I consider that is may be more related to code review

Comment: The goal is to be able to call the A or B property depending on which type is used, like you normally do with many signatures of the same method. But since it's a property it seems to cause troubles. I tried making the parent property virtual and the children override, but to do so the children would have to take Object instead of Decimal, which means I could not call the parent's. Indeed, by casting var1 in my example in class A, that would work, but i'd like as much as possible not to do that for the reasons Steve said. Sorry for not using the class definition, it's my first question.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `new` keyword here:

```
public new decimal Value
```

Using `new` here completely hides `A`'s `Value` property. Maybe you just want `overrides`.